# What should I use to host a public JSON file that rarely changes without redeploying my whole webapp?

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase, hosting

I've a react app hosted on firebase and a realtime database for user data.

Currently, there's a json file in my app's code containing reference data. This file might change once every few months.

Where could I host this file so that I could update it without redeploying the whole webapp?

I thought about using Firebase Storage, but it seems inefficient to download the file on every render. Is there a way to only download it once and cache it for a certain amount of time?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can fetch it the first time and store it in `localStorate`, and about the expiration time, add a key as a specific expiration time, and when time over re-fetch it again, e.g (for three month later):

```
const date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);
const expirationTime = date.getTime();

{
   data: {...some data},
   expirationTime
}
```

and each time you have to check the `expirationTime` if the current time was bigger than `expirationTime` you have to re-fetch the data.

Comment: Is there a way to force the fetching when I change the data in the database even if the current time isn't bigger than the expiration time?

Comment: @SimonTran I dunno exactly, but another way is that you can just put your JSON file in the public folder then fetch it from there!

Comment: But then I would need to redeploy my app every time its updated, right? What would be the best practice in this situation?

Comment: no, u just can change that json file... i have no great idea about a best practice in this case but i will create a simple api server to serve some json files.